# Systemd journal plagued with docker messages

Tags: systemd, docker

I've found that systemd is full of lines like that when I issue `journalctl -f`

> jul 09 21:13:47 newhope.belkin.home docker[1430]:
>   time="2015-07-09T21:13:47-03:00" level=info msg="GET
>   /v1.11/containers/35f101d97881e543d40370ee4242216dfb88103f2947c0446ad0ad03a1bcd810/json"
>   jul 09 21:13:47 newhope.belkin.home docker[1430]:
>   time="2015-07-09T21:13:47-03:00" level=info msg="+job
>   container_inspect(35f101d97881e543d40370ee4242216dfb88103f2947c0446ad0ad03a1bcd810)"
>   jul 09 21:13:47 newhope.belkin.home docker[1430]:
>   time="2015-07-09T21:13:47-03:00" level=info msg="-job
>   container_inspect(35f101d97881e543d40370ee4242216dfb88103f2947c0446ad0ad03a1bcd810)
>   = OK (0)" jul 09 21:13:48 newhope.belkin.home docker[1430]: time="2015-07-09T21:13:48-03:00" level=info msg="GET
>   /v1.11/containers/35f101d97881e543d40370ee4242216dfb88103f2947c0446ad0ad03a1bcd810/json"
>   jul 09 21:13:48 newhope.belkin.home docker[1430]:
>   time="2015-07-09T21:13:48-03:00" level=info msg="+job
>   container_inspect(35f101d97881e543d40370ee4242216dfb88103f2947c0446ad0ad03a1bcd810)"
>   jul 09 21:13:48 newhope.belkin.home docker[1430]:
>   time="2015-07-09T21:13:48-03:00" level=info msg="-job
>   container_inspect(35f101d97881e543d40370ee4242216dfb88103f2947c0446ad0ad03a1bcd810)
>   = OK (0)" jul 09 21:13:49 newhope.belkin.home docker[1430]: time="2015-07-09T21:13:49-03:00" level=info msg="GET
>   /v1.11/containers/35f101d97881e543d40370ee4242216dfb88103f2947c0446ad0ad03a1bcd810/json"
>   jul 09 21:13:49 newhope.belkin.home docker[1430]:
>   time="2015-07-09T21:13:49-03:00" level=info msg="+job
>   container_inspect(35f101d97881e543d40370ee4242216dfb88103f2947c0446ad0ad03a1bcd810)"
>   jul 09 21:13:49 newhope.belkin.home docker[1430]:
>   time="2015-07-09T21:13:49-03:00" level=info msg="-job
>   container_inspect(35f101d97881e543d40370ee4242216dfb88103f2947c0446ad0ad03a1bcd810)
>   = OK (0)

I've noted no error in running docker, any idea?

Comment: Looks like you have debug logging enabled for the `docker` daemon.

Answer (score 0):

> I've noted no error in running docker

And your log output, where every line that you have shown to us is `level=info`, shows no error in running docker.  So you and your log agree.

### Further reading

- https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5198